# fullcalendar: placing an image in center for all days cell

Tags: fullcalendar

I need to show an image in cells based on the event feed. If any data available for particular date, then an image will be displayed in center of cell. If not it should display default image in center of cell. I tried with following code. But I was successful to place image  but not center/where the event data is replaced. And also I the "cross" image should be visible only for `validRange`

Required format is shown in image 3. Please help. Thanks.

```
img = "images/cross.png";
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                contentHeight: 380,
                weekNumbers: false,
                fixedWeekCount: false,
                eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                events: feeder,
                businessHours: true,
                aspectRatio: 1,
                defaultView: 'month',
                showNonCurrentDates: false,
                validRange: {
                    start: '2018-08-01',
                    end: moment()
                },

                eventRender: function (event, eventElement, view) {

                    if (event.imageurl) {
                        eventElement.find("div.fc-content").html("<img src='" + event.imageurl + "' width='25' height='28'>");
                    } else {

                        eventElement.html("<img src='" + img + "' width='25' height='28'>");
                    }

                },
                dayRender: function (date, cell) {

                    cell.html("<img src='" + img + "' width='15' height='20'>");
                }});
```

[image: with <code>dayRender</code> function]
[image: without <code>dayRender</code> function]

[image: Required format]